# How to reduce 3-COLOR to 42-COLOR?

Tags: graphs, np-complete, reductions, colorings

The requirement is that two adjacent vertices have different colors, and max. 42 colors.

I show that $ \text{42-COLOR} $ is in NP and then I must reduce it from $ \text{3-COLOR} $. Here it becomes complicated.

Is it similar to $ k\text{-COLOR} $ for any $k$?

Comment: Do you want to reduce 42-COLOR to 3-COLOR, or the other way around?

Comment: The other way around. $\ 3-COLOR \propto\ 42-COLOR $. Now i noticed my mistake.

Answer (score 5):

For an instance of 3-COLOR, try to add a complete graph of size $k-3$, and add an edge between each new vertex and each old vertex. Now you can prove the new graph is $k$-colorable iff the old graph is 3-colorable.